# How to disable resize pointer in a QWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a PyQt5 GUI. All object are contained in a QWidget. I have set its size using the setFixedSize() method. It is of fixed size and you can't resize it but the resize arrow still shows when you hover over the border.

How can I disable this?

My Code below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, nCode_analysis_set_up):
        nCode_analysis_set_up.setFixedSize(350, 200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    nCode_analysis_set_up = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(nCode_analysis_set_up)
    nCode_analysis_set_up.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
>
> Gives the window a thin dialog border on Windows. This style is traditionally used for fixed-size dialogs.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, nCode_analysis_set_up):
        nCode_analysis_set_up.setFixedSize(350, 200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    nCode_analysis_set_up = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(nCode_analysis_set_up)
    
    nCode_analysis_set_up.setWindowFlags(nCode_analysis_set_up.windowFlags() 
                                         | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
                                        )                                         
    
    nCode_analysis_set_up.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```